# Problema com OAuth2 e PHP para entrar com Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, oauth2, token, oauth

Em meu site possuo a opção do usuário entrar com sua conta do Facebook para armazenar suas criações e etc.. Sempre funcionou bem após a implementação, porém, sem qualquer mudanças em dados ou arquivos, tudo parou de funcionar na quinta-feira a noite. Busquei informações sobre algum erro novo que esteja ocorrendo ao fazer esse tipo de login com OAuth2 e PHP, mas não encontrei nada.
Tive que depurar até chegar o mais próximo de onde ocorria o problema, e existem 3 situações:

1 - Erro 500 dizendo que a página não consegue responder a solicitação (depois usei um `try-catch` para solucionar isso e encontrar onde tudo parava)
2 - Excesso de redirecionamentos tanto do meu site, quanto pelo Facebook (também usei o `try-catch` para ir chegando mais próximo do erro)
3 - Por fim, descobri que o erro ocorria aqui:

```
// Aqui verifico se existe essa variável que recebo do Facebook e vem para o meu site como um parâmetro na URL, e ele realmente está vindo
if ($code) {
    $token = $facebook->getAccessToken("authorization_code", [
        "code" => $code
    ]);
    $_SESSION['userLogin'] = $facebook->getResourceOwner($token);
    header("Refresh: 0");
}
```

Acontece que ao usar um `var_dump` na variável `$token`, recebo duas mensagens de erro diferentes durante as tentativas. Uma diz que o código que já foi utilizado "*This code has been used*", ou então que o código já expirou "*This code authorization has expired*", mesmo que o processo todo leve menos de 10s em geral.
Além disso, outra coisa que reparei é um atributo no *array* que recebo no mesmo `var_dump, e possui o nome "Expires", e está vindo com o valor de "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT", conforme abaixo:

```
 ["headers":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
          array(16) {
            ["WWW-Authenticate"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(81) "OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_code" "This authorization code has been used.""
            }
            ["Content-Type"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(30) "text/javascript; charset=UTF-8"
            }
            ["facebook-api-version"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(4) "v6.0"
            }
            ["Strict-Transport-Security"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(25) "max-age=15552000; preload"
            }
            ["Pragma"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(8) "no-cache"
            }
            ["x-fb-rev"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(10) "Ocultei esse valor por segurança"
            }
            ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(1) "*"
            }
            ["Cache-Control"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(8) "no-store"
            }
            ["x-fb-trace-id"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(11) "Ocultei esse valor por segurança"
            }
            ["x-fb-request-id"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(23) "Ocultei esse valor por segurança"
            }
            ["Expires"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(29) "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
            }
            ["X-FB-Debug"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(88) "Ocultei esse valor por segurança"
            }
            ["Date"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(29) "Fri, 17 Jul 2020 06:10:23 GMT"
            }
            ["Alt-Svc"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(43) "h3-29=":443"; ma=3600,h3-27=":443"; ma=3600"
            }
            ["Connection"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(10) "keep-alive"
            }
            ["Content-Length"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(3) "158"
            }
          }
```

Alguém passou pelo mesmo problema recentemente e conseguiu solucionar?